# I want to find the previous held value in a column and add/replace on current row [Excel VBA]

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am working on a file where I’d like to replace empties to the previous used cargo item
Note: that the vehicle can carry different goods over the span of time. However, I need to only find the most recent item it carried and replace/add on current row.

I am using index match and row to find the highest occurrence to find previous value.
`=INDEX(C$1:C$12,MATCH(MAX(IF($B$1:B1=B2,ROW($B$1:B1),0)),ROW($B$1:B1),0))`

However, it is not the desired result. Can someone help me please?

Please find attached a sample below.

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: Have you thought of using a Pivot Table or is there something that prevents you from doing so?

Comment: I am looking at automating it, as it is part of a process where minimal human interaction is needed. Also the end user may not be tech savvy to manipulate pivot tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here a solution with 1 helper columns.

Look at sheet "Version5" in the file below.

https://1drv.ms/x/s!AncAhUkdErOkgqRyVBgWLxs5aMO34g?e=v2dfMj

```
=COUNTIF($A$3:A3;A3)
{=IF(B3<>"E";B3;IF(A3=A2;D2;INDEX($D$3:D3;MATCH(A3&COUNTIF($A2:A$3;A3);$A2:A$3&$C2:C$3;0))))}
```

The formula in D3 is a matrix formula, don't press Enter when leaving the cell but press Ctrl+Shift+Enter
Don't write the {} yourself, they will come when leaving the cell like i wrote above.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this Prema, however in this method, if say B carried Item 1 again, helper 1 will not reset to 1.  I am attaching the screenshot link here- https://imgur.com/a/3C4wSBO

Comment: Updated the reference picture on main post as well.

Comment: Thank you! I don't think this approach would be feasible as I have over 80,000 rows of data which will grow to over 200,000 rows by mid year. The helper table could get really long.

Comment: wow I really love the way you use Offset. Im learning so much from this. Thank you. I ran into a little bit of a glitch.. It works perfectly until if a vehicle comes in empty without being loaded first. Please see - https://imgur.com/a/b9kik9N
I have updated the reference picture on the main post.

Comment: @ShyamR with the data you share here, one can not know where the item3 (in the row with the red cell) comes from: How do I know if the vehicle is empty it will have item3, is it always item3 or can it be different, if it can be different one needs to know the pattern for that.

Comment: Hi Prema, that item3 (in the red cell), if you look is what vehicle A carried last. It comes from what the vehicle carries last. It needs to find the most recent item it carried. The pattern is random because sometimes the cars come back loaded with goods sometimes they come back empty...

Comment: @ShyamR Now I got a solution. Only two formulas! Please keep in mind that I spend 5-6 hours altogether with your problem in my free time. It would be nice if you also one day could help a stranger with no self-interest. No matter with what. Just to make this world a better one.
Let me know if the solution doesn't work for you.

Comment: I cannot thank you enough @Prema. I learnt a lot from your approach. I think you are really an expert. I will definitely try to help someone in the future in whatever capacity I can. The solution worked beautifully. Again, thank you very much!

Comment: @ShyamR Not an expert at all, I just don't give up so easily. Happy, that it's working for you :-)